# Python aiohttp how to handle client session token timeout

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

I am making several 100's of http request using aiohttp. I am relatively new to the async world but have managed to get the basic code working.

First I am generating a token. Then, making aiohttp calls using this token.
Token has a validity of 30 mins. So I am assuming if my calls run for more than 30 mins then they will start failing.

How do I update my code to plug-in a new token after 30 mins then resume the remaining calls. This my first time implementing async calls, so relatively clueless on how to handle this.

```
async def a_get_all_user_details(urls):
    results = []

    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=70)
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None, connect=300, sock_connect=300, sock_read=None)

    auth_token = get_token()  # token expires in 30 mins
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True, headers=headers, connector=connector, timeout=timeout) as session:
        for url in urls:
            result = asyncio.ensure_future(a_get_user_details(url, session))
            results.append(result)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*results)
        return responses


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(a_get_all_user_details(search_urls))
    user_details = loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's simpler way to do it but here's my take:

The *problem* is that there are many connections *in the fly* when you want to refresh session. When you close the session and create new one, active connections which are waiting for data throw an exception.

In my example I have a list of all sessions and when time arrives I simply create new session (with new token) and append it to the list. The new connections will use the last (freshest) session.

At the end of script I close all sessions.

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

sessions = []


async def get_token():
    return "XYZ"


async def refresh_session():
    # this function periodically refreshes the token every X sec
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=3)
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(
        total=None, connect=300, sock_connect=300, sock_read=None
    )

    while True:
        headers = {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + await get_token(),
        }

        sessions.append(
            aiohttp.ClientSession(
                trust_env=True,
                headers=headers,
                connector=connector,
                timeout=timeout,
            )
        )
        print("New session created")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)  # every 5 seconds refresh session


async def get_user_detail(url):
    # wait for session to show up:
    while not sessions:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    # use last (freshest) session:
    async with sessions[-1].get(url) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        html = await resp.text()
        return f"some result for {url} length of data {len(html)}"


async def get_user_details(urls):
    results = []
    for url in urls:
        results.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_user_detail(url)))

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*results)
    return responses


async def main():
    # some urls to gather:
    urls = [
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "https://www.yahoo.com",
    ] * 30

    t1 = asyncio.create_task(refresh_session())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(get_user_details(urls))

    # finish when first task ends (in this case get_user_details())
    done, _ = await asyncio.wait([t1, t2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    # close all opened sessions:
    for s in sessions:
        await s.close()

    # print the result
    print("Domains gathered ", len(done.pop().result()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This prints:

```
New session created
New session created
Domains gathered  90
```